# More efficient to create new array or reset array

Tags: java

I have an array of 6 elements. Is it more efficient (time-wise) to set those elements to null, or to create a new array? I'm going to be using this array hundreds of times.

Comment: why do you need to set null or create new array? please describe more

Comment: if in doubt: measure. My guess is that creating a new one is more efficient. And my guess is that if you only create 100s of arrays, you won't notice the difference.

Comment: Okay, thanks that makes sense. What is around the maximum number of objects/arrays I can  create before running out of space on the stack?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208655/empty-an-array-in-java-processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bit of code demonstrates that it's **faster to assign each value to null**.
Note that this is valid for arrays with 6 elements. Eventually it may be faster to create a new array.

```
    Object[] array = new Object[6];

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        array[0] = null;
        array[1] = null;
        array[2] = null;
        array[3] = null;
        array[4] = null;
        array[5] = null;
    }
    System.out.println("elapsed nanoseconds: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
    int length = array.length;

    start = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        array = new Object[6];
    }
    System.out.println("elapsed nanoseconds: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
    length = array.length;
```

and the output:

```
elapsed nanoseconds: 264095957
elapsed nanoseconds: 17885568039
```

Comment: In your case most of the time is probably taken by the GC which would not be that significant in OP's case of 100s of arrays. Interesting anyway

Comment: If you repeat this test by changing Integer.MAX_VALUE to 1000 to reflect the actual usage, both times drop to 0.

Comment: @staticx, thanks. I've fixed it using nanoseconds. (but not that the high number of iterations reduce the error produced by the currentTimeMillis method).

Comment: I am not clear on the mechanics of the loop there, but if you do a simple assignment (not up to Integer.MAX_VALUE), the assignment itself is faster. Because you keep re-assigning a new array of Object size 6 up to Integer.MAX_VALUE when all you need to do is array = newArray. There is no need for the second loop.

Comment: The loop is repeating the operation. (You might have misread the code?)

Comment: The first loop is correct. The second is unnecessary. There is only one array. Why overwrite the array up to Integer.MAX_VALUE? You are not overwriting individual positions but the entire array 2^31-1

Comment: both loops are correct or both loops are incorrect. They do the same in different ways. In the first loop, each iteration sets all content of the array to null. (You might have misread the code?)

Comment: You are creating 2^31-1 `Object`s in the second loop. That's not needed. Just do `Object newArray = new Object[6];` then `array = newArray`. `array` has 6 elements. Plus, you are right, you don't need to do go to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` because that is wasteful and you are introducing other variables that aren't needed in this efficiency test. Just iterate over what you need in the first loop. Second loop, remove it. You are probably hitting the GC and it is slowing you down over this pointless throwing away and creation of objects.

Comment: If I do that, newArray will change once I change array. You are not making a copy, just changing the reference of array.

Comment: @HélioSantos: It doesn't matter because if you create a null array, assign `array` to `newArray` and then later on some time later do the same thing again, they are independent operations. Taken by themselves, which is what is going on here, it is faster than iterating through each element. The OP is not creating all these objects in a loop.

Comment: he does not want a null array. he wants a array with 6 null objects

Comment: Semantics. What I am saying is that if you take an array of 6 null objects (which is what I was trying to say - call it `newArray`) and assign it to `array`, that is what the OP wants to do. Not iterate and create 2147483647 `Object`s

Comment: I'm not creating 2147483647 Objects. I'm creating 2147483647 arrays that can hold up to 6 Objects. Each of the 6 indexes of the array is null. You can't do that by assigning newArray to array because they are references to the same object. The OP understood my answer...

Answer (score 6):

I would use this method.

[System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

It is native and pretty efficient.

I would keep an array of nulls and copy it into my array using this method, each time when I want to reset my array. So my advise would be not to create a new array each time, but also not to loop (using Java code) and set the elements to null yourself. Just use this native method which Java provides.

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test056 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] arrNull = new String[10000];
        String[] arrString = new String[10000];

        long t1 = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
            System.arraycopy(arrNull, 0, arrString, 0, arrNull.length);
        }

        long t2 = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(t2 - t1);

        long t3 = System.nanoTime();

        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
            Arrays.fill(arrString, null);
        }

        long t4 = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(t4 - t3);
    }

}
```

Comment: @assylias No... Basically I advise not to create a new array each time.

Comment: Or `Arrays.fill(myArray, null);` would be better

Comment: @staticx System.arraycopy is a native method, an optimized one AFAIK. Have you seen what the code of Arrays.fill does? Not only does a trivial loop but before that does a few checks. How is it going to be better?

Comment: You don't need to have an array of nulls hanging around. You can just efficiently assign null to every position of the array.

Comment: But that's just not true IMHO. Updated my answer with an example. Arrays.fill is about 3-4 times slower, it seems.

Comment: If you are measuring elapsed time, and you want it to be correct, you must use System.nanoTime(). You cannot use System.currentTimeMillis(), unless you don't mind your result being wrong.

Comment: The purpose of nanoTime is to measure elapsed time, and the purpose of currentTimeMillis is to measure wall-clock time. You can't use the one for the other purpose. The reason is that no computer's clock is perfect; it always drifts and occasionally needs to be corrected. This correction might either happen manually, or in the case of most machines, there's a process that runs and continually issues small corrections to the system clock ("wall clock"). These tend to happen often. Another such correction happens whenever there is a leap second.

Comment: Since nanoTime's purpose is to measure elapsed time, it is unaffected by any of these small corrections. It is what you want to use. Any timings currently underway with currentTimeMillis will be off -- possibly even negative.

You may say, "this doesn't sound like it would ever really matter that much," to which I say, maybe not, but overall, isn't correct code just better than incorrect code? Besides, nanoTime is shorter to type anyway.

Comment: I might still be wrong in my estimations of "more efficient" or "faster", but at least it will remove some doubt here I hope :)

Comment: Thanks. You try the nano, still 3-3.5 times faster.

Comment: You are right, it is faster. Thanks for providing the proof :)

Comment: @staticx And thank you for letting me know something new about the nano.

Comment: Hey, we can't all know everything and I was wrong too! Have a great day

Comment: Looks like creating a new array and assigning it is faster. https://ideone.com/a276aV .. I didn't try it with actual data instead of null

Comment: @staticx I see. It could be, yes ... but my guess is on the long run this will be compensated by the GC cleaning up all these unused arrays which we create each time we need to reset our array :) This is what I based my answer on from the 1st minute. Anyway, enough digging for me today into this.

Answer (score 3):

Mu - You are not asking the right question.

Do not worry about the efficiency of such trivial operations until it is a known performance bottleneck in your application.

You say you will be nulling/creating 6 references 100s of times. So, you will be creating/nulling/looping < 6000 references. Which is trivial in modern programming.

There are likely much better places where you should be spending your development time.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new array should be more efficient **time-wise** because it would only allocate empty references.
Setting the elements to null would imply walking through the entire array to set references to null (which is default behavior on array creation) which is more time consuming (even if for an array of 6 elements it's totally negligible).

EDIT : time-wise is bold because memory-wise is may not be your best option. Since you'll be creating new references, if you instantiate new object, make sure the object of your previous array are garbage collected properly (again, with only 6 elements it must be gigantic objects to see any bad performance impact).

Comment: Isn't that exactly what is being done when you set each value of the array equal to `null`?

Comment: Well then why would this be more efficient if they do the same things under the covers? See for example this answer on a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9314345/1864167

Comment: Zero-ing an array is a lot more efficient than creating a new array because the JLS will require the new array to be zero-d anyways.

Comment: Jeroen : sorry misread your question. 
staticx : The new array will only creates null references so I think it's the fastest you can get.

Comment: I'm not sure.. can we time it?

Comment: Jeroen : If any optimizations done by the JVM on array allocation resemble those of C/C++, the allocated memory of references is "adjacent" to each other which I believe is much faster than instantiating, say, a List of disparate references. So I think we're not talking about the same thing as the related answer of your link since it's talking about List (maybe the memory allocation process of an arrayList is the same as it is for an array... in which case I totally agree. But that's a particular case).
staticx : could be interesting indeed :)

Comment: Looks like yours is fastest. https://ideone.com/a276aV .. I didn't try it with actual data though

Answer (score -4):

The best and secure way to create an array is the next one:

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>(0);
```

So can can regenerate by this way the array each time you want. You don't need to set to null. By this way, the array is destroyed and regenerated in memory.

You can read more info in Oracle Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

Comment: array!=List. Just because it's named ArrayList, this doesn't mean it is an array

Comment: ArrayList is one of the two possible List implementations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html.

Comment: Yes, but we are talking about arrays, not lists.